# ¿Por qué un "peluco" es un reloj ostentoso?

Tags: etimología, españa, coloquialismos, sustantivos

La RAE define *peluco* como:

> **[peluco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SQHuyZ4)**
>
> De or. inc.
>
> 1. m. jerg. Esp. Reloj ostentoso de pulsera o de bolsillo.

Se expresa que es de origen incierto. En el CORDE aparecen registros de su uso desde 1961:

> *—Lo primero que hago en cuanto gane unas perras —dice Pilete— es comprarme un peluco: un buen peluco con su correa flexible, un peluco dorado que parezca de oro.*
>
> Alfonso Grosso, "La zanja", España (1961)

Igualmente, en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España encuentro este artículo titulado "[La vida entre los rateros](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003413855&page=5&search=peluco&lang=es)", publicado el 28 de enero de 1930, lo que sitúa a la expresión aún más atrás en el tiempo:

> Un día, por ejemplo, *el Manco*, que le llaman así —¡vean ustedes lo que son las cosas!— porque da unos tortazos que encienden la cara, y porque se vale del truco de esconder uno de los brazos para operar mejor, había *hecho* un *peluco* (reloj) y una *tralla* (cadena) *zapando* (hurgando) en la *guardilla* (bolsillo del pecho de la americana) de un *pasmao* (uno que mira un escaparate).

(El artículo, por cierto, es una mina de posibles preguntas sobre la jerga de los rateros.)

¿Es posible averiguar cuál es el origen de la palabra *peluco*, o al menos dar alguna pista sobre el mismo? ¿Tendrá algo que ver con el pelo o vello corporal del brazo?

Comment: Pues parece que tiene que ver con las pelucas... [¿Por qué se denomina al reloj como peluco?](https://elsalondecris.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/por-que-se-denomina-al-reloj-como-peluco.html)

Comment: @fedorqui pues igual sí que tiene que ver con el pelo, pero de otra forma... :)

Comment: @fedorqui la RAE define _pelucón_ desde 1780 como "aumentativo de peluca, llaman comunmente así al que la trae con fantasía y ostentacion". ¿Te animas a una respuesta?

Comment: Agregué el tag España. Hace tiempo que van apareciendo preguntas de regionalismos españoles de los que no he oido una jota (morcilla, pelillos, tocino, flor en el culo...).

Comment: En mi entorno, *peluco* es jerga para *reloj* (de pulsera o de bolsillo), no necesariamente ostentoso

Comment: @Luis sí, yo también le he dado ese sentido tradicionalmente. Dije "ostentoso" por ser la definición del diccionario (que, recordemos, refleja la expresión escrita y no la oral).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copio de [¿Por qué se denomina al reloj como peluco?](https://elsalondecris.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/por-que-se-denomina-al-reloj-como-peluco.html):

> Hace tiempo en España era habitual oír frases como “que peluco más bonito tiene”, o “que peluco te habrá costado una pasta”, refiriéndose al reloj. Un termino popular muy castizo y español, pero ¿cual es el origen de dicha expresión?
>
> El origen lo encontramos en tiempos muy remotos y vinculados a las monedas españolas.
>
> Entre los siglos XVI al XIX circulaban unas monedas de oro conocidas como 8 escudos u onzas.
>
> Hasta el siglo XVIII estas monedas presentaban un diseño denominado como de “cruz” porque por un lado se representaba el escudo y por otro lado una cruz patada.
>
> A  partir de dicho siglo hay una modificación de los cuños y se sustituye la cruz patada por la imagen del rey, pero **como la moda en el siglo XVIII, entre la alta nobleza, era de llevar peluca, al rey se le representaba con una peluca.**
>
> [image]
>
> Popularmente a estas monedas se las conocía como peluconas. Aunque por el  decreto del  19/10/1868 nace la peseta, todavía se usaba el término de moneda peluconas simbolizando lo caro, lo ostentoso, etc.
>
> A los relojes de bolsillos también se le denominaba “relojes pelucones” y luego pasaron a denominarse pelucones, y de ahí derivo el término de “peluco” para referirse a este instrumento de tiempo.

El artículo focaliza en las monedas *peluconas*. Sin embargo, hacia el final habla de *se usaba el término de moneda pelucona simbolizando lo caro, lo ostentoso, etc*. Ahí surge mi premisa: tener un reloj en el siglo XIX no debía ser demasiado común, por lo que pasaba automáticamente a ser un artilugio caro, ostentoso.

Además, si no ando equivocado, los relojes de la época eran de los de bolsillo con la cadenita, tan similares a estos:

> [image]

En ellos, la tapa suele tener un dibujo o motivo muy parecido a los que pueden aparecer en una moneda.

Juntándolo todo, a mí me da la sensación que se acabó asociando *moneda pelucona* con *reloj*, luego con *reloj pelucón* y, a base de ir perdiendo *pelucona* su acepción de moneda y popularizándose el de reloj, convirtió *reloj pelucón* en *pelucón/na* a secas.