# ¿Por qué se denomina "luca" a mil pesos?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, argentina, uruguay

En [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20849/1674) a [¿Se usa “kilo” como “millón” en Hispanoamérica?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20836/1674), pablodf76 comenta que:

> (...) en Argentina (y creo que en Chile) mil unidades monetarias locales (pesos o lo que fuera) se llaman coloquialmente una luca.

Mirando en el DRAE constato el hecho:

> [**luca**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NdzzpBX)
>   1. f. coloq. Arg., Col. y Ur. Mil pesos.

Y lo mismo con el Diccionario de americanismos:

> [**luca**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=jenPyFAfBx0AvZCYcO6).
>   I.  1.  Ar, Ur, pop; Ch, pop + cult → espon. Cantidad de dinero equivalente a mil pesos.
>   2.  f. pl. Co. Dinero. pop.
>
> a. ǁ    de a ~.
>   i.  loc. adj. Ec, Bo. Referido a cosa material, barata o de mala calidad. pop.
>   ii. Ec, Bo. Referido a precio, bajo. pop.
>   iii.    Ec. juv. Referido a persona o cosa, que no sirve.

Sin embargo, no encuentro el origen etimológico de la palabra. ¿Alguien sabe de dónde viene su uso?

Answer (score 5):

Hay unas cuantas páginas que dan fe de su origen. Por ejemplo en 24horas.cl se comenta en [¿Por qué le decimos "luca" al billete de mil pesos?](http://www.24horas.cl/tendencias/espectaculosycultura/por-que-le-decimos-luca-al-billete-de-mil-pesos-1760759):

> El origen de la historia cuenta que, en el siglo XVIII., en España le llamaban a unas monedas las "peluconas", debido a la presencia de un personaje que usaba este atuendo típico para aquel entonces.
>
> Nuestro país, en su condición de colonia hispánica, inevitablemente comenzó a adoptar el modismo y así vincularlo al dinero criollo.
>
> Sin embargo, el paso de los años permitió que el nombre se fuera acortando lentamente, pasando a "peluca" hasta quedar como la conocemos hoy: luca.
>
> Pero la evolución del término fue transversal de nuestro país, porque en Uruguay, Argentina y Colombia también lo usan para denominar a las divisas locales.

Lo cual enlaza con el uso de [*peluco* para nombrar un reloj ostentoso](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19132/1674), por la presencia de la peluca del rey en las monedas:

> como la moda en el siglo XVIII, entre la alta nobleza, era de llevar peluca, al rey se le representaba con una peluca.

Comment: Si bien etimologias de chile ofrece [otras hipótesis](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?luca), de momento me quedo con esta.

Comment: Del origen no tengo ni idea, pero lo usamos mucho en Colombia y desde hace mucho tiempo. Una pequeña búsqueda muestra que es de uso muy común en casi todo suramérica. [luca](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Luca.php) y  [lucas](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Lucas.php)

Comment: En algún foro alguien menciona que nunca han existido monedas en España con un personaje usando peluca. ¿Algún numismático Español que pueda validar esto?

Comment: @fedorqui Etimologías de Chile publica cualquier cosa: entre más teorías sobre un mismo término, mejor. No debe ser considerada una fuente científica.

Comment: ¿No tiene nada que ver con *lucro*, entonces?

Comment: @DGaleano mira [mi respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19132/1674) a _¿Por qué un “peluco” es un reloj ostentoso?_. Ahí sale una moneda con peluca :)

Comment: El enlace que nos deja @Rodrigo hace posiblemente válida la hipótesis. Si la "Pelucona" existió en el "Nuevo Reino de Granada" que **pelucona** haya evolucionado a **luca** es factible.

Comment: [8 escudos u "onza pelucona"](https://www.numespa.es/la-reina-de-las-monedas-espanolas)

Answer (score 3):

A pesar de que la versión de las "pelucas" -indicada por fedorqui- me parece la más convincente, existe la posibilidad de que su origen esté en el *caló* (la lengua de los gitanos españoles). En realidad ambas versiones no tendrían por qué ser excluyentes. La expongo acá porque me parece entretenida, principalmente a partir de "Apuntaciones sobre el caló bogotano" (Max Leopold Wagner, 1950) y de un googleo rápido.

En caló de fines del siglo XIX, "peseta" se decía *lúa*, palabra cuyo origen no remite a las "pelucas", sino al argot antiguo francés, a la palabra ***luque***, [ya detectada en 1628](https://books.google.cl/books?id=VuT91RX6cssC&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=luque#v=onepage&q=luque&f=false), 150 años antes de la onza pelucona con el perfil de Carlos III. Hay que aclarar que estas "lúas" corresponden a las pesetas, no a las onzas peluconas.

*Luque* significaba "certificado falso", y probablemente derivaba de la villa de Lucques, una localidad francesa en la que se comerciaba la seda. Posteriormente *luque* pasó a significar también "naipes" en la germanía (o sea en el lenguaje de los delincuentes), y de ahí pasó como "lúa" al caló y a la jergas española, portuguesa y americana, donde también podía significar "luz" y "prostituta" (aunque toda esta confusión está poco clara, y se mezcla con la de la palabra española *lea*).

A partir de *lúas*, en un juego de palabras típico de "los bajos fondos", a la baraja se le dijo "masselucas" (el Maese Lucas), palabra que aparentemente permaneció en el lunfardo rioplatense.

El paso de "los naipes" a "las monedas" no parece disparatado, sobre todo considerando que en la jerga popular es muy fácil saltar de un significado a otro por mero sentido del humor.